# Diretório de arquivo txt com VBS

Tags: script, vbs

Meu código em VBS está assim:

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
filename = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Copy_File.txt"
oShell.Run(filename)
```

Existe alguma maneira de eu deixar esse arquivo txt que necessito de acesso dentro de minha pasta (do script) e buscar ele, sem precisar de um caminho literal?

Ex: Script dentro da pasta Copy, arquivo txt dentro da pasta Copy e caminho passado no *filename* algo como: `..\Copy`?

Dessa maneira ainda não consegui.

Answer (score 2):

Você consegue capturar o diretorio atual através do objeto [Scripting.FileSystemObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50(v=VS.85).aspx):

```
Dim oShell, oFso

Set oShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

DiretorioAtual = oFso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
Arquivo = DiretorioAtual & "\Copy_File.txt"

oShell.Run(Arquivo)
```